# Checkbox enabled by mouse

Tags: organisation

I have a list of tasks to accomplish and all are listed in a working sequence.

I wish there were empty checkboxes to remember that no task was performed.

Suppose I perform 3 tasks from a list of 5 tasks.

With this I would save the file with 3 tasks executed.

The next day, I would like to open the file and see only the 3 tasks performed with checks

I was able to create some checkboxes, but they do not have this property to be marked with the mouse.

Is there any possibility of this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

Item 1 \mbox{\ooalign{$\checkmark$\cr\hidewidth$\square$\hidewidth\cr}}

Item 2 \mbox{\ooalign{$\checkmark$\cr\hidewidth$\square$\hidewidth\cr}}

Item 3 \mbox{\ooalign{$\checkmark$\cr\hidewidth$\square$\hidewidth\cr}}

Item 4 \mbox{\ooalign{$\checkmark$\cr\hidewidth$\square$\hidewidth\cr}}

Item 5 \mbox{\ooalign{$\checkmark$\cr\hidewidth$\square$\hidewidth\cr}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hyperref` checkboxes.  Doesn't work in every viewer though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
  Item 1 \CheckBox[width=1.3ex,height=1.3ex]{}

  Item 2 \CheckBox[width=1.3ex,height=1.3ex]{}

  Item 3 \CheckBox[width=1.3ex,height=1.3ex]{}

  Item 4 \CheckBox[width=1.3ex,height=1.3ex]{}

  Item 5 \CheckBox[width=1.3ex,height=1.3ex]{}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Here the checked boxes in the Evince viewer.

[image]

Comment: Can Adobe Reader have this function?

Comment: @LCarvalho Adobe Reader can do it.

Comment: I think I'll have to find the correct setup of my Acrobat Redader DC because I could not use.